Issue with Decrypt Function: ValueError - Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode
I'm encountering an error when trying to decrypt data using AES CBC mode in Python's Crypto library. Here's my decrypt function:
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad

def decrypt_file(file_path, key):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as encrypted_file:
        ciphertext = encrypted_file.read()

    iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
    encrypted_data = ciphertext[AES.block_size:]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

    padded_plaintext = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_data)
    plaintext = unpad(padded_plaintext, AES.block_size)

    with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(plaintext)


When I try to run this function, I encounter the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Code/rsa.py", line 87, in <module>
    decrypt_file(item_path, b'Sixteen byte key')
  File "/home/user/Code/rsa.py", line 52, in decrypt_file
    padded_plaintext = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_data)
  File "/home/user/Code/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_cbc.py", line 246, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Data must be padded to %d byte boundary in CBC mode" % self.block_size)
ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode

It seems like the issue arises from the padding of the plaintext before encryption. I've used pad from Crypto.Util.Padding during encryption, but during decryption, it's throwing this error related to padding.
I'm wondering why I'm encountering this error and how I can resolve it. Any insights or suggestions would appreciated. Thank you!

Can you add your encryption function to the question as well?
